# Prototype JS adds "fire" attribute to every element in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, magento, prototypejs

I've seen this when scanning the DOM in IE where PrototypeJS is present: a `fire` attribute is added to many elements, presumably as part of some trick to extend element functionality. Here's what I mean:

[image: Prototype JS adds fire attribute to most elements]

Now, I remember seeing this specifically in `IE lte 8`, but just today I noticed it in IE11, after trying to troubleshoot some new JS bugs in Magento (1.4.x, meaning Prototype 1.6.0.1).

**Does anybody know why Prototype does this to elements, and if it's causing problems in IE11?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fire method is how a synthetic event is sent by an element on the page, which can then be subscribed to by observer methods elsewhere. Read more here: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/fire/

Unless you are also trying to define a fire() method on your elements, you may safely ignore this. It does not have any side-effects that I'm aware of.

Comment: @GeekNum88, unfortunately that's not  an option. As I said in the post, we are running Magento 1.4 which is tightly integrated with Prototype (1.6), and simply updating Prototype to 1.7 could create more problems.

Comment: @Walter, thanks for the answer. From the docs/source I can see how `fire` is implemented.